# Unable to paint on Gtk drawing_area with Cairo

Tags: c++, gtk, cairo

I am trying to paint a point on `drawing_area` in `Gtk` with `cairo`. 
I have two functions, `do_drawing` function to paint the background on `draw` signal, and the second one `do_drawPoint` to draw a point.

```
void painter::do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
cairo_paint(cr);    
}

void painter::do_pointDraw(cairo_t *cr)
{
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
cairo_arc(cr, 150, 150, 10, 0, 2 * M_PI);
cairo_fill(cr);    
}
```

Now, the `drawPoint` function is called whenever user clicks on the `drawing_area`.

```
void drawingArea::drawPoint()
{
g_signal_connect(area, "button-press-event", 
  G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);
std::cout<<"drawPoint"<<std::endl;
}

gboolean clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, cairo_t *cr,
gpointer user_data)
{
if (event->button == 1) {
    x = event->x;
    y = event->y;
}
std::cout<<x<<" and "<<y<<std::endl;
ptr->do_pointDraw(cr);
gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
}
return TRUE;
}
```

But after printing values of `x` and `y`, the program terminates with segmentation fault.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff74ac3ae in cairo_set_source_rgb ()
```

What might be causing this? Am I proceeding correctly?

Comment: You might want to recheck the code you pasted: it probably can't compile as it is (please fix the indenting if you do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to read the code (with broken indentation and with only snippets provided), but some things to note:

- `button-press-event` handler signature is incorrect. The cairo context is not there.
- Drawing should happen *only* inside the `draw` signal handler of GtkDrawingArea. The idea of drawing on button press is just not how Cairo works: user interaction should change the state of your app, draw-handler should draw based on the current app state.
- `button-press-event` handler is connected inside  `drawPoint ()`. This sounds very wrong.

I suggest you try reading the [DrawingArea docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html) and start with the simple example it gives, and then start adding more complex things when that works.

Comment: Yes, this guide here: [Gtk-Getting-Started](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-getting-started.html) helped me!